# Dealing with quotes in UGC using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a log parser for a game I have an interest in, and I've run into problems when a user has double quotes in their username. The following line is an example of a username without double quotes, as to provide some context to the problem:

```
L 02/02/2015 - 20:30:17: "bowser<10><[USERID]><Blue>" triggered "damage" against "mario<3><[USERID2]><Red>" (damage "50") (realdamage "37") (weapon "sniperrifle")
```

With my current regex `\\\"(.*?)\\\"` It works just fine. I am able to identify the first username(bowser), the event(damage), and the second username(mario), along with the damage and realdamage values. However, the problem is introduced when a user has quotes in their name, as bowser doesin this line:

```
L 02/02/2015 - 20:30:36: "mario<7><[USERID]><Blue>" triggered "damage" against "bowser -"The Ship Sets Sail"<12><[USERID2]><Red>" (damage "60") (realdamage "10") (weapon "sniperrifle")
```

When I parse that line, I get the first name correct, and the event name correct. However, when I read the second name, I get `bowser -` and when I read the damage, I get `<12><[USERID2]><Red>` resulting in a NumberFormatException

1. It is not known how many quotes will be in the user's name
2. It is not known if the user's name will contain other characters that could mess with the other parsing(I have anglebrackets set up as well as parentheses)
3. It is not known how long the user's name will be

I would love some hints in the right direction.

Comment: Will the user's name always end with `<Red>` or `<blue>` tags?

Comment: There will always be a <Red> or <Blue> tag at the end of the user field, but it is unknown if the user will have <Red> or <Blue> as part of their actual username. It would fail less if I used those as the termination of the username, but still have a chance at failing.

Comment: The problem with allowing everything is.. Your regex can fail *anywhere*. You have to prevent the user from entering certain characters as user name.

Comment: I have no control over the usernames, as you can change your name on steam anytime and without restrictions.

Comment: What all data do you need to extract?

Comment: The desired output is as follows: `mario<7><[USERID]><Blue>, damage, bowser -"The Ship Sets Sail"<12><[USERID2]><Red>, 60, 10, sniperrifle`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by isolating the name using constants that are very unlikely to occur, then I stored the usernames in a `List<Player>` and I sanitize each line before extracting information, as to prevent dirty characters.